# Жизнь не молодая и жизнь немолодая?

Tags: частица-не

В каком случае пишется вместе, а в каком раздельно (правописание частицы **не** с прилагательными)?

*Не молодая*

Comment: @Карина, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.

Answer (score 3):

Всё зависит от контекста.

"Не молодая" употребляется как отрицание молодости, имеется в виду противопоставление свойства существительного (имеющегося или подразумеваемого контекстом) молодости.

В то время как "немолодая" ближе по значению к словам "зрелая" или "старая".

При наличии в предложении союза "а", однозначно пишется раздельно. Также стоит учитывать, что при раздельном написании смысловая нагрузка приходится на частицу "не".

Без соответствующего контекста невозможно ответить на вопрос "слитно или раздельно", так как возможны оба варианта написания, а в некоторых предложениях они и вовсе взаимозаменяемы.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что такое "жизнь (не)молодая". Молодая жизнь – понятно, так говорят. Мол, "сгубил свою молодую жизнь"... И тому подобное – в похожих, а также в менее скорбных контекстах. )))